# How to migrate in laravel without losing the data after renaming the column name?

Tags: laravel, migration

Scenario: I create a column name `price` which have lots of data and now I need to change that 'price' Column name to oldPrice without losing it's data and using migration.
Is there any way please let me know. Thanks

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do or undo any changes in migrations. You must write new migration this will not let you or your team mates lose any data and your app will not break.

To make change in column use following :

Make a migration

```
php artisan make:migration change_price_to_old_price --table=table_name
```

and use below code according to your requirements.

**In up() function:**

```
public function up(){
   Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->renameColumn('old_name', 'new_name');
   });
}
```

**In down() function** just undo what you did in `up()`

```
public function down(){

   Schema::table('table_name', function (Blueprint $table) {
       $table->renameColumn('new_name', 'old_name');
   });
}
```

**Recommendation:**
Always write `down` migration to undo what you are doing in your `up` function.
**php artisan migrate:status** to see which migrations have ran and which are remaining.

hit **php artisan migrate:** and see list of commands and learn about them

Comment: Okey, but i need to migrate to run this migration, right? I guess which will flush all the datas.

Comment: No. not at all. Above command will create a new file in `database directory` there you will write code to rename your column. when you will run `php artisan migrate` then latest migration will run and it will only change column name and your data will be there without single change

Comment: @SandeshPoudel let me know if it solved your problem

Comment: @AfrazAhmad Would it be okay if you should include an example `down()` method in your answer.

Comment: @OluwatobiSamuelOmisakin  I have updated my answer answer